# Mocha test scripts in sub-directories are executed locally, but ignored in CircleCI

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, circleci

To me, it looks like mocha's `--recursive` flag is working correctly on my machine, but being ignored during CI automated testing.  This means that only 60 tests are executed in CircleCI, but ~100 are executed when I run `npm test` on my machine.

**Partial Project Structure**

```
|--/test
|----mocha.opts
|----lifecycle.test.js
|----/integration
|------/models
|--------Thing.test.js
|------/controllers
|--------/thing
|----------thingAction.test.js
|--/.circleci
|----config.yml
```

**mocha.opts**

```
--recursive
--timeout 20000
--reporter list
--exit
```

**.circleci/config.yml**

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:8.11

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: yarn install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: yarn test
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
},
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run lint && npm run mocha-tests && echo 'Done.'",
  "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo 'Your .js files look so good.' && lesshint assets/styles/ --max-warnings=0 && echo 'Your .less files look good, too.'",
  "mocha-tests": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/lifecycle.test.js test/integration/**/*.test.js",
}
```

In this example, both `Thing.test.js` and `thingAction.test.js` are being executed localy, but only `Thing.test.js` is executed during the CircleCI build. Put another way, `test/integration/**/*.test.js` matches both file names locally, but only the top subdirectory in CircleCI.

**How do I make sure all the test scripts get run?**

Comment: The question has been answered, but anyone finding this later might find this bug discussion useful: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be solved by giving a single quote in your test command when defining targeted test files so it would be

```
"scripts": {
  "mocha-tests": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha 'test/lifecycle.test.js' 'test/integration/**/*.test.js'",
}
```

Without quote, glob pattern won't work correctly especially in linux environment.

Comment: That makes sense. As you implied, I am using Windows in dev.  With your change, tests are running in CircleCI just fine. Unfortunately, it's failing in Windows. You wouldn't happen to know a cross-platform variation, would you?

`> node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha './test/lifecycle.test.js' './test/integration/**/*.test.js'

    Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: 'test/lifecycle.test.js'
    Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: 'test/integration/**/*.test.js'`

Comment: Never mind. I tried out escaped double quotes and it worked like a charm. `"mocha-tests": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \"test/lifecycle.test.js\" \"test/integration/**/*.test.js\"",` Thanks for your help.